# Failed to set executable permission for gradlew - bitrise

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, bitrise

I'm trying the deploy workflow, ios build well, but I got this error in

`install-missing-android-tools`

```
Preparation
Set executable permission for gradlew
Failed to set executable permission for gradlew, error: chmod : no such file or directory
|                                                                              |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| x | install-missing-android-tools@2 (exit code: 1)                | 2.86 sec |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

my deploy workflow
[image: workflow]

[image: missing-component]

Answer (score 0):

Reach out to Bitrise support imo. They'll ask for a link and support access (can be turned on in the settings) they are usually very helpful in my experience. Might be something wrong with the step or the environment temporarily

Comment: hey! thanks, I did it and waiting response from yesterday :(
I just skip android Steps, for now, Now I faced another issue I will update the Q

Comment: I just put them here https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/unable-to-deploy-into-testflight/18054 to prevent messy in this question, can u check it, please!